# Excessive bias produces bootstrapped confidence intervals which do not include nor the observed mean nor the bootstrapped mean

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

For one statistic (the estimate of a model) I have the following results:

```
boot<-boot(datos.sc, var.impo, R = 5000, sim="ordinary", stype="i")
boot
        original        bias    std. error
t*  1.850292977 -5.158119e-01  0.22875954
```

My problem is that i get the following confidence intervals:

```
boot.ci(boot, type = c("all"))
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 5000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = boot, type = c("all"), index = i)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   ( 1.918,  2.814 )   ( 1.913,  2.836 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 0.864,  1.787 )   ( 1.887,  2.498 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Warning : BCa Intervals used Extreme Quantiles
Some BCa intervals may be unstable
Warning messages:
1: In boot.ci(boot, index = i, type = c("all")) :
  bootstrap variances needed for studentized intervals
2: In norm.inter(t, adj.alpha) :
  extreme order statistics used as endpoints
```

My questions are:

1) How introduce the boostrap variances needed for the studentized interval?
2) Why just the percentile interval includes the observed value of my statistic?

2) It is very strange for me, as the mean of the bootstrap values is smaller than the observed value, and the cis are higher than both the observed value and the bootstrapped mean

Comment: If you look at the four bootstrap confidence intervals, one of them is not like the others.  Without knowing the details of your model, it's hard to make any definitive statement about why this is, but this could happen if you have a small number of outliers which strongly influence the point estimate if enough of them are in the data used to estimate the model, it seems to me.  You might want to check for outliers as the next step.

Comment: The different one is percentile ci which is the one without bias correction. The boostrapped estimates are actually estimates of an averaged model with MUMin package. I fit all the models with robust estimates so I don´t think outlayers are the problem. Maybe the problem is how bootstrapping affect the estimates of the different models used for building the average model, but I ´ve checked the histogram of the bootstrapped estimates and they have a normal distribution, but they are left biased, while the confidence intervals are right deviated from the observed value, as you can see above.